# TouchableOpacity onPress doesn't work inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, touchableopacity

(*iOS Only*)
`<TouchableOpacity>` doesn't respond if it is inside of a `<ScrollView>` :

1. It works properly in the simulator but not in a real device,
2. `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` doesn't make any difference
3. Partial code:`<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.xButton} onPress={() => this._onClose()}>`

any suggestions?

--- ***Code update*** -----

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.xButton} onPress={() => this._onClose()}>
    <Image style = {styles.xImg} source = {require('../../images/xbtn.png')}/>
   </TouchableOpacity>
     {this._renderPricing()}
     {this._renderServices()}
 </ScrollView>
```

and the Styling looks like this:

```
scrollView:{ 
    width: width,
    height: height,
}, xButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    marginTop: '1%',
    marginRight: '3%',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',

},xImg: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    aspectRatio: .6,
    opacity: 0.5,
},
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Have you tried a release build?

Comment: @PatNeedham Unfortunately I don't get any errors. If I tap the button multiple  times eventually it will work. I have seen similar questions saying that `<TouchableOpacity>` inside of a `<ScrollView>` only works if you double tap it but this doesn't seem to be the case here. 
Yes @MattyK14 I tried a release build and it behaves the same.

Comment: Could you elaborate little bit more by providing us your code? Make sure your "TouchableOpacity" component has a defined width and height. Also, try adding some sort of empty child inside of it, like "<View />" for example.

Comment: @BluDay I updated my question. So everything i have in there is working properly except from the TouchableOpacity, which as i mention above works in the simulator .

Comment: Why do you want to use `TouchableOpacity` when you can use `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableWithoutFeedback` ? Do you really need the opacity effect on your button?

Comment: Last time I used it I remember that the `TouchableHighlight` had an effect that I don't want, but I will try both and I will let you know.

Comment: Try wrapping your touchable opacity in a standard view, this seems to work for me

Comment: The issue was solved. It was caused because in my separate rendering methods the `this._renderPricing` etc etc I was changing the state too many times and the JS thread was occupied so the  TouchableOpacity couldn't respond to touch events see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html for more details if you need. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved. It was caused because in my separate rendering methods the `this._renderPricing` etc I was changing the state too many times  therefore the JS thread was occupied so the TouchableOpacity couldn't respond to touch events see [RN documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) for a more detailed explanation if needed. Thank you very much for your answers.